# What is the general way to use WeakReference when object was destroyed?

Tags: java

Please help me check the below codes, if the Car-object was destroyed by GC, I want to recover the program logic, according to the common practice, are my codes correct?

```
Car car = new Car();
WeakReference<Car> mWeakReference = new WeakReference<Car>(car);
mWeakReference.get().run();
...
if (mWeakReference.get() == null) {
    Car newCar = new Car();
    mWeakReference= new WeakReference<Car>(newCar);
}
mWeakReference.get().run();
```

Comment: what are *"codes"* supposed to be? What is *"recover program logic"* supposed to mean? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: If you need the ```Car``` object to exist, then why use a ```WeakReference```?

Comment: If you don't want the GC to destroy your object, don't use a WeakReference. Instead, use the real object

Comment: See a WeakReference as a tourist guide, that _can_ take you to a clothes vendor - but you should never buy from the guide himself, the vendor may not longer be there.

Comment: Sorry for my unclear question, assume my program run for hours, and memory is not enough, the car-object will be destoryed by GC. Then if my program still want to use car-object again, this way I have to create a Car-object again, My question is if the older WeakReference<Car>-object is also useless, I also need create a new one to hold the new Car-Object?

Comment: ... yes, reference-objects are bound to their value, you need to re-set your variable entirely ... keep racing-conditions in mind if you use more than 1 thread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not super clear what you are asking (as specializt said). But there's a bug in the code. See the comments below.

```
if (mWeakReference.get() == null) {
    Car newCar = new Car();
    mWeakReference= new WeakReference<Car>(newCar);  //instance set on weakref
} // maybe GC runs here
mWeakReference.get().run(); //instance could be null
```

A more correct approach would be (not too clean though)

```
Car car = mWeakReference.get();
if (car == null) {
    car = new Car();
    mWeakReference= new WeakReference<Car>(car);
} 
car.run();
```

Comment: Hey, I just realised my code is wrong too! as it doesn't re-use the weak reference! I just updated it.

Answer (score 0):

No, the weakreference could have been destroyed again.  instead, re-use the:
Car car; reference, and run that, that way you have a hard reference, and it can't be GC'd.